# How to send free SMS in android..i want to know WhatsApp,Wechat ..this type of messeging applications how provide us sending messege for free

Tags: android, sms, sms-gateway

This is my Code for sending SMS

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SMSTest extends Activity
{
Button btnSendSMS;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
```

Called when the activity is first created.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sendingsms);
btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage); 

btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
else
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
"Please enter both phone number and message.",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
}
```

sends a SMS message to another device

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{

String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
new Intent(SENT), 0);

PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

//—when the SMS has been sent—
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
switch (getResultCode())
{
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
}
}, new IntentFilter(SENT));

//—when the SMS has been delivered—
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
switch (getResultCode())
{
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
}
}, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
}
```

This code is to receive the SMS

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
//—get the SMS message passed in—
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";
if (bundle != null)
{
//—retrieve the SMS message received—
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
str += " :";
str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
str += "\n";
}
//—display the new SMS message—
Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
}
```

And this is the XML file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter the phone number of recipient"
    />
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Message"
    />
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150px"
    android:gravity="top"
    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send SMS"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Very basic application ..i need to know is it possible to send SMS through coding ...if not then how whatsApp gives us permission to send sms for free..does they pay??..or we can use some API...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WhatsApp doesnt use Operator-based SMS in the application, simply WhatsApp has its own servers, when you open the app, you're connected to their server, when your friend also login, both of you are connected to the server, so at this moment there is an open channel between both of you, You use it to chat and send files ,  etc

Simple, isn't it :)

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp doesn't send SMS's to the other device. The messages are sent via IM - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol

Comment: how to use IM for sending free SMS

Comment: You don't send a free SMS. See Tarreq's answer for how WhatsApp's servers work for message sending. Basically, you'll send data from you're phone via Internet to WhatsApp where the message is forwarded to the recipient. There is no SMS transactions at all